# configtxgen -- Has Invalid Keys: Organizations with latest hyperledger-fabric 1.1.0-rc1

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Following is my configtx.yaml
It is failing to generate the genesis block with following error
'Profiles[HealthwiseChannel].Application' has invalid keys: Oragnizations
2018-03-13 16:24:43.389 IST [common/tools/configtxgen] func1 -> CRIT 003 Error unmarshaling config into struct: 1 error(s) decoding:

- 'Profiles[HealthwiseChannel].Application' has invalid keys: Oragnizations
  panic: Error unmarshaling config into struct: 1 error(s) decoding:
- 'Profiles[HealthwiseChannel].Application' has invalid keys: Oragnizations [recovered]
  panic: Error unmarshaling config into struct: 1 error(s) decoding:
- 'Profiles[HealthwiseChannel].Application' has invalid keys: Oragnizations

yaml file:

Capabilities:
    Global: &ChannelCapabilities
        V1_1: true
    Orderer: &OrdererCapabilities
        V1_1: true
    Application: &ApplicationCapabilities
        V1_1: true

Organizations:
    - &OrdererOrg
        Name: OrdererOrg
        ID: OrdererMSP
        MSPDir: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/healthwise.com/msp
        AdminPrincipal: Role.ADMIN
    - &insuranceOrg1
        Name: insuranceOrg1
        ID: insuranceOrg1MSP
        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/insuranceOrg1.healthwise.com/msp
        AdminPrincipal: Role.ADMIN
        AnchorPeers:
            - Host: peer0.insuranceOrg1.healthwise.com
              Port: 7051
    - &insuranceOrg2
        Name: insuranceOrg2
        ID: insuranceOrg2MSP
        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/insuranceOrg2.healthwise.com/msp
        AdminPrincipal: Role.ADMIN
        AnchorPeers:
            - Host: peer0.insuranceOrg2.healthwise.com
              Port: 7051

Orderer: &OrdererDefaults
    OrdererType: solo
    Addresses:
        - orderer.healthwise.com:7050
    BatchTimeout: 2s
    BatchSize:
        MaxMessageCount: 10
        AbsoluteMaxBytes: 98 MB
        PreferredMaxBytes: 512 KB
    Kafka:
        Brokers:
            - 127.0.0.1:9092
    Organizations:
        - *insuranceOrg1
        - *insuranceOrg2
    Capabilities:
        <<: *OrdererCapabilities

Application: &ApplicationDefaults
    Organizations:
        - *insuranceOrg1
        - *insuranceOrg2
    Capabilities:
        <<: *ApplicationCapabilities

Profiles:
    HealthwiseOrdererGenesis:
        Capabilities:
            <<: *ChannelCapabilities
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *OrdererOrg
            Capabilities:
                <<: *OrdererCapabilities
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *OrdererOrg
            Capabilities:
                <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
        Consortiums:
            HealthwiseConsortium:
                Organizations:
                    - <<: *OrdererOrg
                    - <<: *insuranceOrg1
                    - <<: *insuranceOrg2
    HealthwiseChannel:
        Capabilities:
            <<: *ChannelCapabilities
        Consortium: HealthwiseConsortium
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Oragnizations:
                - *OrdererOrg
                - *insuranceOrg1
                - *insuranceOrg2
            Capabilities:
                <<: *ApplicationCapabilities

Please help me figure out what is the mistake i am making.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are running "configtxgen" in the same path where configtx.yaml is located

Answer (score 0):

It can be a case of version mismatch. Make sure your version of binaries match the configuration files.